# Monsters aren't spawning because of an error I cant fix

Tags: lua

I need help with a lua script im currently making for a game.

```
    addhook("ms100", "MONSTERms100")
function MONSTERms100()
    t = t + 1
    if t % 100 == 0 then
        while #MONSTERS < CONFIG.MAXMONSTERS do
            local rand, spawnNo, mapName
            while true do 
                rand = math.random(#CONFIG.MONSTERS)
                mapName = CONFIG.MONSTERS[rand].spawn[map'name'] and map'name' or CONFIG.DEFAULTMAP
                spawnNo = math.random(#CONFIG.MONSTERS[rand].spawn[mapName])
                if math.random(0, 100) < CONFIG.MONSTERS[rand].spawnchance[mapName][spawnNo] then
                    break
                end
```

**LUA ERROR: sys/lua/waffle/monsters.lua:411: attempt to get length of field '?' (a nil value)
 -> sys/lua/waffle/monsters.lua:411: in function**

I checked multiple times, couldn't find a solution. The error didn't happen to me before, and I did not edit anything in this file. It started when I updated the game. So what am I trying is to control the monsters spawning, but they are not spawning at all right now. This is my first time asking for help, sorry if I forgot some details. Thank you if you try to fix this for me because i'm dumb.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> sys/lua/waffle/monsters.lua:411: attempt to get length of field '?' (a
>   nil value) -> sys/lua/waffle/monsters.lua:411: in function

tells you that you're trying to get the length of a `nil` value in the file monsters.lua line 411.

```
while #MONSTERS < CONFIG.MAXMONSTERS do
```

`#` is the `length operator`

From [Lua Reference Manual 5.3 - 3.4.7 The Length Operator](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7)

> The length operator applied on a table returns a border in that table.
>   A border in a table t is any natural number that satisfies the
>   following condition:
>
> `(border == 0 or t[border] ~= nil) and t[border + 1] == nil`
>   In words, a border is any (natural) index in a table where a non-nil
>   value is followed by a nil value (or zero, when index 1 is nil).
>
> A table with exactly one border is called a sequence. For instance,
>   the table `{10, 20, 30, 40, 50}` is a sequence, as it has only one
>   border (5). The table `{10, 20, 30, nil, 50}` has two borders (3 and 5),
>   and therefore it is not a sequence. The table `{nil, 20, 30, nil, nil, 60, nil}` has three borders (0, 3, and 6), so it is not a sequence,
>   too. The table `{}` is a sequence with border 0. Note that non-natural
>   keys do not interfere with whether a table is a sequence.
>
> When `t` is a sequence, `#t` returns its only border, which corresponds to
>   the intuitive notion of the length of the sequence. When t is not a
>   sequence, `#t` can return any of its borders. (The exact one depends on
>   details of the internal representation of the table, which in turn can
>   depend on how the table was populated and the memory addresses of its
>   non-numeric keys.)
>
> The computation of the length of a table has a guaranteed worst time
>   of O(log n), where n is the largest natural key in the table.

So in simple words, `MONSTERS` has not been defined yet. So you cannot get the number of its elements. As you're using `CONFIG.MONSTERS` a few lines later I presume using `#CONFIG.MONSTERS` should solve the problem. Given that that's the table you actually want to use. But without knowing the rest of your code I can only guess.